# Monospace fonts , quotes, and circumflex a

Tags: windows, fonts, quote, monospace

Most of the monospace fonts normally used for programming on Windows (all I have found so far) don't display 'funny quotes' (0xE2) properly. For example, an error message from the gcc compiler like

> warning: conflicting types for built-in function âprintfâ

which is really

> {funny quote}fname{funnyquote}

displays in Ludida Console, DejaVu, etc. as

> {circumflex a}fname{circumflex a}

(It may be doing so for you right now). Is there a a helvetica-like monospace font that respects that particular 8-bit codepage?

Answer (score 1):

Windows has a split personality. Most of it is based on Unicode, while some parts still rely on code page character translations.

The character you're getting for 0xE2 is the proper Unicode translation, and is the same in the very common [code page 1252](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) and most of the rest as well. The only code page that has a quote for that value is [code page 10000, Mac OS Roman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_10000).

The `chcp` command is used to change the code page of the command window, but I can't get it to work for your specific case.